# Align divs on top while they're aligned also on left

Tags: html, css

**1)** 
I've got 2 divs, placed in 1 big div (container for them). They're supposed to be like small cards with informations. Here, I have a problem. When I have 2 cards next to each other and one card is simply higher, second one moves like it's aligned to bottom of 1st card, but I want to have it aligned allways on top (here is a code and fiddle).

```
    <div class="main-cards">
        <div class="card" style="width: 65%;">
            <h1>CARD 1</h1>
            <p>small</p>
            <p>small</p>
            <p>small</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 25%;">
            <h1>CARD 2</h1>
            <p>small</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    .main-cards{
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        top: 150px;
        text-align:center;
        background-color: #6ab5dd;
    }
    .card{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: white;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    }
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4px7kc4v/2/

How I want it:
[image]

**2)**
How could I do 3 cards vertically centered in one big container to center, but in this layout? (look at img)

[image]

Because I have this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/sx7ryv70/

Thanks for everyone's time! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**
Add this to the css of the cards:

```
      vertical-align: top;
```

**2)** Having div's as `inline-blocks` force them to be on the same 'row' as if they are huge text characters. Try fitting the smaller cards together in their own container.

Comment: Yes! My hero ! :D Tank you so much for your time, I see, and answer is pretty simple, I'm such a dumb but what could I do. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align: top; to .card

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions:

1. `[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Atula/4px7kc4v/3/)`
2. `[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Atula/sx7ryv70/1/)`

Answer (score 0):

Here look at this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx7ryv70/)

## HTML

```
<div class="main-cards">
        <div class="card" style="width: 55%; height: 300px; float:left;"></div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 55%; height: 300px; margin-top: 50px; float: left;"></div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 25%; height: 650px;"></div>
```

## CSS

```css
    .main-cards {

      position: relative;

      height: auto;

      width: 80%;

      margin-left: auto;

      margin-right: auto;

      top: 50px;

      text-align: center;

      background-color: #6ab5dd;

      padding: 30px;

    }

    .card {

      display: inline-block;

      background-color: white;

      height: auto;

      margin: 10px;

      margin-top: 40px;

      padding: 8px;

      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);

    }
```

All you need to remember is the floating principle.